# Перегрузка оператора в классе

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Не получается перегрузить оператор сравнения "<".
Использую Qt.
point.h

```
class Point
{
private: 
double x;
double y;
double z;
...
public:
double getX();
double getY();
double getZ();
...
friend bool operator<(Point &first, Point &sec);
}
```

point.cpp

```
...
bool Point::operator<(Point &first, Point &sec)
{
return sqrt(first.getX()*first.getX() + first.getY()*first.getY() + first.getZ()*first.getZ()) <
sqrt(sec.getX()*sec.getX() + sec.getY()*sec.getY() + sec.getZ()*sec.getZ());
}
```

main.cpp

```
...
QList<Point> list;
...
qSort(list.begin(), list.end());
...
```

При такой реализации выдает ошибку:

```
...\point.cpp:23: ошибка:    'bool Point::operator<(Point&, Point&)' must take exactly one argument
bool Point::operator<(Point &first, Point &sec)
                                                   ^
```

Если убираю второй аргумент:
point.h

```
...
friend bool operator<(Point &first);
...
```

point.cpp

```
...
bool Point::operator<(Point &first)
{
    return sqrt(first.getX()*first.getX() + first.getY()*first.getY() + first.getZ()*first.getZ()) <
            sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
}
...
```

То выдает:

```
...\point.h:46: ошибка: 'bool operator<(Point&)' must take exactly two arguments
     friend bool operator<(Point &first); 
                                       ^
```

Подскажите в чем проблема, и как сделать что бы работало.

---

Записываю в .h внутри класса

```
friend bool operator<(const Point &first, const Point &sec);
```

в .cpp

```
bool operator<(Point const &first, Point const &sec){ 
   return sqrt(first.getX()*first.getX() + first.getY()*first.getY() + first.getZ()*first.getZ()) <
    sqrt(sec.getX()*sec.getX() + sec.getY()*sec.getY() + sec.getZ()*sec.getZ());
}
```

Выдает ряд однотипных ошибок (на каждый get)

```
...\point.cpp:24: ошибка: passing 'const Point' as 'this' argument of 'double Point::getX()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     return sqrt(first.getX()*first.getX() + first.getY()*first.getY() + first.getZ()*first.getZ()) <
                            ^
```

Comment: к делу не относится, но `operator<` для точек выглядит не очень естественно, т.к. множество точек не образуют порядка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявленный оператор не соответствует реализованному.

```
friend bool operator<(Point &first, Point &sec); // объявляет его как свободную функци.
```

соответственно реализация должна быть без префикса класса:

```
bool operator<(Point &first, Point &sec)
```

И еще `const` не хватает в сигнатуре:

```
(Point const & first, Point const & sec)
```

и можно обойтись без `friend` и объявлять его вне класса так как оператор вроде как вызывает только общедоступные методы, не требуя доступа к `protected` и `private`.

Comment: Исправил, но теперь выдает другие ошибки.

Comment: @Василий Это оттого, что не хватает `const` квалификаторов у геттеров. `double getX() const;`

Comment: Да, действительно. Теперь все работает. Спасибо.